# GetAssemblies Method Root Location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");

    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        var entityTypes = assembly
          .GetTypes()
          .Where(t =>
            t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PersistentAttribute), inherit: true)
            .Any());

        foreach (var type in entityTypes)
        {
            entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
              .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
        }
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The code works and I have no issues with it, however, I am trying to understand it completely.  The thing that I do not understand is this part:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

I do not understand where it pulls its assemblies from.  Does the list come from project references?  Does it come from the bin folder, looks at all the dll's maybe and brings back a list?  How does this work?  I need to understand this properly because I am trying to implement Ninject with this and if I do, there will be no references to some of the dll's and I still need them to be considered in this method.

EDIT: Let me restate the question: If I put a test.dll inside my project's bin folder and call GetAssemblies method, will my test.dll be part of its results?  If the answer is no, how do I get test.dll to be part of its results so that I can use it, without actually referencing the test.dll in the main project.

Comment: **AppDomain.GetAssemblies()**.This method gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the execution context of this application domain.
You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ArturLavrov I've read that, and many others, the problem is I don't actually understand what they mean to say when they say things like: 
"Gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the execution context of this application domain"  I'm trying to understand this in simpler terms.

Comment: @Bagzli I recommend you read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43wc4hhs(v=vs.90).aspx).It  describes the relationship between application domains and assemblies.